# How do I disconnect from Wi-Fi network with programming language c

Tags: c

I have a small project in C language and I want to implement the program, the program cuts off the WiFi network

Comment: You will need to access os specific functionality for this.

Comment: You need to specify which o/s you're planning to do this on, because the answer will be radically different on Windows and Linux — and probably quite different on *BSD and macOS too.  It can be done; that's the good news.  But it is more an issue of operating system calls needed than it is a question of programming in C.  The programming will be relatively simple once you know what calls to make.

Comment: Thanks. I will do some research on the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example disconnect through a terminal command.

e.g. in Windows OS

```
system("netsh wlan disconnect");
```

example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("netsh wlan disconnect");
    system("echo Wifi disconnected!");
    return 0;
}
```